# Sorting a string in mips

Tags: string, sorting, selection, mips

I have a program that will sort a string using a selection sort algorithm method. The program will take in a string entered by the user and sort it using the selection sort algorithm. My problem is when I run it I get an error saying that "fetch address not aligned on word boundary." What should I do to fix this? I am relatively new to programing in mips.

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "\n\nEnter an string of characters: "
result: .asciiz "\n\nHere is the string you entered: "
buffer: .space 80
length: .word  80
before: .asciiz "Before sort:\n"
space:  .asciiz " "
after:  .asciiz "\n\nAfter Sort\n"
newLine: .asciiz "\n"

.text
.globl main

main:   
#Prints the prompt string
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt 
syscall 

#reads string from user and saves in $a0
li $v0, 8
la $a0, buffer
li $a1, 80
syscall 

#Prints the result string
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, result 
syscall

#Prints the string entered by the user
la $a0, buffer 
li $v0, 4
syscall     

li      $t5, 0      # t5 is k = 0

la      $t7, length     
    lw      $t7, 0($t7)     # t7 = length

addi    $t8, $t7, -1    # t8 = length - 1
la  $t6, 0($a0) # t6 = address of the array

outerLoop: slt  $t0, $t5, $t8   # if k < length - 1  t0 = 1
beq $t0, $zero, breakOuterLoop # k >= (length - 1)
add $t9, $zero, $t5 # t9 is min = k

addi    $t1, $t5, 1     # t1 is j = k + 1

innerLoop: slt  $t0, $t1, $t7   # if j < length t0 = 1
beq $t0, $zero, breakInnerLoop

add $s3, $t9, $t9   # s3 = 2 * min
add $s3, $s3, $s3   # s3 = 4 * min
add $s3, $a0, $s3   # s3 is address of list[min]
lw  $t2, 0($s3)     # t2 is list[min]

add $s0, $t1, $t1   # s0 = 2 * j
add $s0, $s0, $s0   # s0 = 4 * j
add $s0, $a0, $s0   # s0 is address of list[j]
lw  $t3, 0($s0)     # t3 is list[j]

slt $t0, $t3, $t2   # if list[j] < list[min] t0 = 1
beq $t0, $zero, secondIF # skip min = j & ++j and jump to secondIF
add     $t9, $zero, $t1 # min = j
j secondIF

secondIF: beq   $t9, $t5, incrementJ # if min != k swap, else goto incrementJ

# BEGIN SWAP :
add $s0, $t9, $t9   # s0 = 2 * min
add $s0, $s0, $s0   # s0 = 4 * min
add $s0, $s0, $a0   # s0 = address of list[min]
lw  $t4, 0($s0)     # t4 is temp = list[min]


add $s1, $t5, $t5   # s1 = 2 * k
add $s1, $s1, $s1   # s1 = 4 * k
add $s1, $a0, $s1   # s1 = address of list[k]
lw  $s3, 0($s1)     # s3 = list[k]


sw  $s3, 0($s0)     # list[min] = list[k]

sw  $t4, 0($s1)     # list[k] = temp 
addi    $t1, $t1, 1 # ++j
add $t9, $zero, $t5 # t9 is min = k  
# END SWAP

j innerLoop 

incrementJ: addi $t1, $t1, 1    # ++j
j innerLoop

breakInnerLoop: addi $t5, $t5, 1 # ++k
j outerLoop


breakOuterLoop:             


#Prints the result string
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, result 
syscall

#Prints the string entered by the user
la $a0, buffer 
li $v0, 4
syscall

 exitProgram:   li $v0, 10  # system call to
syscall         # terminate program
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are trying to sort characters, but you appear to be using instructions `lw` and `sw` which are intended for full words while characters of a string are single bytes.

`lw` and `sw` will fail if the supplied address isn't word aligned (as would happen if looking through each character in a string).

Comment: should I use lb and sb instead or should I use something else?

Comment: If you mean to store and load bytes (one character) then yes; `lb` and `sb` are the appropriate instructions

Comment: I fixed that but the result printed is just empty. Any suggestions?